# Powershell Selenium IE - Click on innerHTML element

Tags: powershell, selenium, internet-explorer, click, innerhtml

I am trying to make a script in powershell that clicks automatically on my jobs local page. However, I have a problem clicking this element:

```html
 <A onclick="top.frames[1].frames[1].showProgressMeter();submitCommand(event,'com_tibco_wfc_TreeView_905296379', 'com_tibco_wfc_DefaultFrame_1141616262', false, false, 'null', 's', '6', false);; return false;" class=Text href="#" name=null>Application Management</A>
```

I tried many thing and don't know what to try next...
Please help me and tell me if you need more info.

Comment: Please post the code you have already tried.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have one element with the text "Application Management", you could find the element using something like this:

```
$Driver = ... # Setup Selenium driver
$Element = Find-SeElement -Driver $Driver -TagName A | Where-Object { $_.Text -eq 'Application Management' }
Invoke-SeClick -Element $Element # Click the element
```

Comment: I wish this worked but it just breaks:
Find-SeElement : The term 'Find-SeElement' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Comment: I guess I should add that I was using the selenium-powershell module [here](https://github.com/adamdriscoll/selenium-powershell). This does work though; I've used this.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the following code to use the `FindElementByXPath` method to find the element based on the text value.

```
$link = $seleniumDriver.FindElementByXPath("//a[contains(text(),'Application Management')]")

$link.Click()
```

The detail sample code as below:

```
#add references to the Selenium DLLs 
$WebDriverPath = Resolve-Path "E:\Projects\PowerShellSamples\WebDriver.dll"
#I unblock it because when you download a DLL from a remote source it is often blocked by default
Unblock-File $WebDriverPath
Add-Type -Path $WebDriverPath

$WebDriverSupportPath = Resolve-Path "E:\Projects\PowerShellSamples\WebDriver.Support.dll"
Unblock-File $WebDriverSupportPath
Add-Type -Path $WebDriverSupportPath

#before we start, we must ensure all zones are running either in protected mode, or not.  They need to all be the same.
#(we might be able to negate the requirement for some of these using InternetExplorerOptions.IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings)

#set protected
#local
#New-ItemProperty "hkcu:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\0" -Name "2500" -Value 0 -PropertyType DWORD -Force | Out-Null
#internet
#New-ItemProperty "hkcu:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\1" -Name "2500" -Value 0 -PropertyType DWORD -Force | Out-Null
#intranet
#New-ItemProperty "hkcu:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\2" -Name "2500" -Value 0 -PropertyType DWORD -Force | Out-Null
#trusted
#New-ItemProperty "hkcu:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\3" -Name "2500" -Value 0 -PropertyType DWORD -Force | Out-Null
#restricted
#New-ItemProperty "hkcu:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\4" -Name "2500" -Value 0 -PropertyType DWORD -Force | Out-Null

#can pass this stuff in when we instantiate driver if needs be (if we want a chromeless browser for example)
$seleniumOptions = New-Object OpenQA.Selenium.IE.InternetExplorerOptions
#open this URL when Internet Explorer launches
$seleniumOptions.InitialBrowserUrl = "<the website url>";


#provide the selenium options to the Internett Explorer driver (calling this opens the IE session)
$seleniumDriver = New-Object OpenQA.Selenium.IE.InternetExplorerDriver -ArgumentList @($seleniumOptions)

#click button 

$link = $seleniumDriver.FindElementByXPath("//a[contains(text(),'Application Management')]")

$link.Click()

#we don't close it in this instance because we want to keep the browser open as a dashboard view
#$seleniumDriver.Close()
#$seleniumDriver.Dispose()
#$seleniumDriver.Quit()
```

Edit: In my sample, the website resource as below:

```
<a onclick="javascript:alert('hello')" class="Text" href="#" name="null">Application Management</a>
```

Comment: doesn't work for me:
Exception calling "FindElementByXPath" with "1" argument(s): "Unable to find element with xpath == //a[contains(text(),'Application Management')]"

Comment: Please try to use F12 developer tools to check the html elements, whether it contains this link, in my sample the html resource as below: `<a onclick="javascript:alert('hello')" class="Text" href="#" name="null">Application Management</a>`